# How to check for identical Vectors concurrently?

Tags: matlab

Trying to check for identical vectors. Currently using the `isequal` function to check for identical ones.

It runs like this.
`if isequal (vectorA, vectorB) == 0`
 It will then run an instruction.
`end`

`if isequal (vectorA, vectorB) == 1`
 It will run another instruction.
`end`

I now have a set of vectors more from A to F. Is there anyway to check all of them (B,C,D,F) against Vector A and do the same thing as mentioned?

Meaning
`if vectorA matches any of B,C,D,F == 0`

The same with the second case where
 `if vectorA matches any of B,C,D,F == 1`

The vectors are constantly changing and this is running in a loop to check for identical vectors. Seems like the isequal function only works between 2 Vectors.
all the vectors are `1xi` where `i can be a number up to 50`
ANY help in this would be greatly apreciated!

Comment: In fact `isequal` can handle multiple input arguments and test whether they are all the same. `isequal(A,B,C)` However, you will always want to have 1 matrix rather than 50 vectors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done very easily with ismember:

To check whether it a vector matches any of the rows:

```
v = 1:3
M = [1:3;2:4;3:5]

ismember(v,M,'rows')
```

To check whether it matches all of the rows, you can extend it by also checking something like:

```
size(unique(M,'rows'),1)==1
```

This assumes that the vectors are stacked below each other, but of course it is easily adjusted to match the situation when they are next to each other.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you keep your other vectors in a matrix rather so something like:

```
a = vectorA;
B = [vectorB, vectorC, vectorD, vectorE];
```

Then just use a simple for loop:

```
flag = false;
for k = 1:size(B,2)
    flag = flag || isequal(a,B(:,k));
    if flag 
        break
    end;
end
```

or if you prefer a completely vecotrized one-liner over the loop (but in this case, I suspect the early exit clause in the loop might actually provide a performance benefit, depends on your data though):

```
flag = any(all(bsxfun(@eq,a,B)))
```

then

```
if flag
    %// do stuff if any was equal
else
    %// Do stuff if none were equal to a
```

BTW if you wanted to check if they **ALL** match instead of if **ANY** match then change to:

```
flag = all(all(bsxfun(@eq,a,B)))
```

or in the loop change to

```
flag = true;
for k = 1:size(B,2)
    flag = flag && isequal(a,B(:,k));
    if ~flag 
        break
    end;
end
```

Comment: @Divakar, you should just make that sort of edit yourself ;) nothing stopping you editing my answers if there is an obvious error like that.

Comment: Sorry, I deleted my comment too early. Well I did made an edit to someone else's code and seemed like that is "frowned" upon here :)

Comment: @Divakar no worries. In my opinion, if it is as clear as in this case, then it's totally fine. If it's a matter of style or optimizes the code etc then I would comment like you did. But that's just me. I guess commenting is the safe option.

Answer (score 0):

To check if `A` equals any of `B`, `C`, `D`, `F` (with possibly different sizes), use [`cellfun`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/cellfun.html) on a cell array containing your vectors:

```
if any(cellfun(@(x) isequal(A,x), {B,C,D,F}))
```

If all vectors are row vectors with an equal number columns, it may be faster to use [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) on a matrix containing your vectors:

```
if any(all(bsxfun(@eq, A, [B; C; D; F]).'))
```